# Numbering subsubsections in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering, sections-paragraphs

I tried using 
`\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]`
but this does not seem to work.

Here is a full example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
  \subsection{Subsection 1.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.1.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.1.2}
  \subsection{Subsection 1.2}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.2.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.2.2}

\section{Section 2}
  \subsection{Subsection 2.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.1.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.1.2}
  \subsection{Subsection 2.2}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.2.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.2.2}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With the output being

[image: Output of the above simple example]

Comment: Do you really need `subsubsections`? Quoting the manual: _We strongly discourage the use of subsubsections in presentations. If you do not use them, you will give a better presentation._

Comment: Well, I am making a set of presentations for a course, which spans about 500 frames. It has to be broken down into sections, which are like course chapters, spanning a number of lectures. Each chapter is broken down into lectures, and sometimes there are distinct topics in the same lecture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm afraid the template `subsubsections numbered` does not exists...

But you can create it:

```
\defbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{subsubsections numbered}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=3em%
 \rlap{\hskip-3em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}%
 \inserttocsubsubsection\par}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\defbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{subsubsections numbered}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=3em%
 \rlap{\hskip-3em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}%
 \inserttocsubsubsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
  \subsection{Subsection 1.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.1.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.1.2}
  \subsection{Subsection 1.2}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.2.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.2.2}

\section{Section 2}
  \subsection{Subsection 2.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.1.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.1.2}
  \subsection{Subsection 2.2}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.2.1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2.2.2}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Simple and nice, You saved my day!